# Magento2 variable in transactional email

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, transactional-mail, variables

I would like to **add customer email** to **order confirmation email**, but can't figure out how to do that. Is there any predefined variable that i can use in Transactional email templates or what does it take in order get customer email in each order confirmation email?

Answer (score 2):

You can get customer email by below line,

```
{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}
```

Comment: This worked for me in M2.4.0.

Comment: @rakesh, how do i redirect the user to sales order history page by setting url in order confirmation email

Answer (score 1):

```
<p >{{trans "Customer Email," customer_email=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used in email template:

```
{{var customer.email}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Juste use `{{var}}` or `{{trans}}` :

```
<h2>{{trans "Dear, %name" name=$customer.name}}</h2>
```

or

```
<h2>{{trans "Dear,"}} {{var $customer.name}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `{{var order.customer_email}}` and `{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}` working in 2.3.4.