# Magento2 - Add customer email address in order email

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, transactional-mail

I'm trying to add customer email address under the billing section of transactional email.

For transactional email I tried 
[this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175492/magento2-variable-in-transactional-email)

but it is not working.

I also tried to add whith no success that variable under Customer Address Templates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share your transactional email code?

Comment: Try using `{{var order.customer_email}}`.

Comment: Try this : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/stores/attributes-customer.html

Comment: Not working :-(